# Is the Material Design NavigationView not yet compatible with AndroidX?

Tags: android, dependencies, material-design, androidx

I just converted my App from the support library to AndroidX. Everything compiles now and the App starts successfully. However one of my activities uses `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView` which seems to still depend on the old support library. Specifically I see dependencies on the following classes if I look into the code of NavigationView:

```
import android.support.annotation.DimenRes;
import android.support.annotation.Dimension;
import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RestrictTo;
import android.support.annotation.StyleRes;
import com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenu;
import com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter;
import com.google.android.material.internal.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout;
import com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.AbsSavedState;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources;
import android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl;
import android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray;
```

In my apps build gradle I depend on:

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01"
```

Since I am using the new dependency to the material design library (which is the one also given my the AndroidX migration guide), I was expecting all the classes having the correct dependencies. Am I wrong here? Is this not ready yet? Does someone have any additional insights I am missing?

Answer (score 10):

I was also facing the same issue, for me adding following dependency in gradle worked.

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

**EDIT latest stable version available is:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

Comment: This is quite old. We have solved the issue back then but I can not remember how. I've handed Android development to a colleague and focused on iOS for the last months, so unfortunately I cannot really tell if your solution is valid.

Comment: Yes, this is old. Actually, I was googling for a similar issue but found this question that was unanswered, after solving, I thought I should answer this, could help others.